# Real time events on salesforce

Tags: api, event

I'm working on app that needs to get events from salesforce (login\logout\create entity\view entity..).
I found a way to get events only after 24 hours (using shield), is there an option to get the events in real time?

Another question, is there an api to get administrative events in real time?